# Can't access GPIOs when switching to systemd, but why?

Tags: linux, bash, embedded, systemd, buildroot

I'm using this ARM AT91 Sam9x5ek Embedded Device, with my Linux Images made by a Buildroot. Usually my `init-system` is `Busybox`, now I changed it to `systemd`. Since then I can't access the GPIO anymore, or at least I can't change the value:

This is the working script I use for changing a pin with the Busybox init system:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo 104 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio104/direction
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio104/value
```

Now my embedded device *with systemd*, runs everything but the last line (setting the actual value). I'm logged in as root, so permission right should actually not be the problem.

This is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=USER: Camilo - GPIO

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/exec_camilo
ExecStop=/home/setDownGPIO

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anybody know why this happens? And has somebody an idea how to fix it ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you get an error message? Is this script being run as a systemd service?

Comment: It's running as systemd service, and I get no error messages. When I `cat` the pin, It shows my always the value from the very beginning, doesn't matter to which values I force it to put.

Comment: Does `systemctl status your-service-name.service` give anything useful?

Comment: unfortunately not more than that it's enabled (I updated the post with the service file)

Comment: Your service file is going to execute *really* early, since it doesn't have any `After=` ... It may just be coming up too early (e.g., before the GPIO driver is loaded, or somesuch). Not sure how that interacts with `Type=idle` personally. If you restart your service (after boot), does it work?

Comment: the service is initialized just before log in, so this shouldn't be a problem. Restarting leads to the same results. The more I think about, the more strange it sounds to me: that an init-system forbids something on the already running system.

Comment: Does just running those lines from your root shell work? Maybe it somehow broke that GPIO in general on your box... Could also try rmmod and modprobe the module(s) involved and see if it works after that (which would indicate systemd somehow loaded them in a way they didn't expect).

Comment: Shouldn't be the service file, since when I put a line into the script like `echo this is a test`, then it's printed when the script is called - well I'm about to try modprobe but I don't think that it's about initializing, but more about access permissions - Do I need to call a special function to change the GPIO value ? or is my script alright ?

Comment: Your script looks fine, and you should have permission to the file (and if you didn't, you should see an error about it when you did the `systemctl status`). That's why I'm curious if its working from the shell after boot...

Comment: Sadly here too no difference has been made. May it be caused by the Kernel ? I'm using an old 2.6.39 - but again with BusyBox or SysV init-system it's doing the job without any problems.

Comment: I would guess systemd loaded something in the wrong order. A compare of dmesg (e.g., `diff` or `vim -d`) from BusyBox/SysV boot vs. systemd boot might give some clues. Not sure if 2.6.39 prefixed all the lines with a since-boot timestamp, but if it did, you'll need to remove (or change to `[X]` or similar) those before feeding to `diff`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try on that, let's see if we find the bug.